# Define merge strategy per branch

Tags: gitlab, git-merge

I would like to know if we have the possibility to define a transparent merge strategy in the repo, that is to say:

I have two branches Master and Dev, I would like to define merge strategy "ours" in the repo, so when the user clicks merge on the gitlab page it does something equivalent to :

```
git config --global merge.ours.driver true
git merge dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't it is possible to set the merge strategy per branch.
Here is a suggestion that is still open: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/27442.